# AvaloniaUI: Heterogeneous TreeDataGrid nodes

Tags: c#, .net, avaloniaui

I want to use the TreeDataGrid in order to show a hierarchy with heterogeneous elements. All samples I have seen use nodes of the same type (e.g., Person).

For simplicity and because I cannot share confidential data about my use case, let's say my data structure is similar to a Team -> Players structure. The **Team** has a *name* and a *city*, while a **Player** has a *name* and *age*. (In my particular use case, there will be only one level of depth, like in this toy example)

I have implemented this using a fictitious **TeamPlayerNode** that mixes both classes Team and Player - this is a screenshot from the resulting UI, and it is roughly what I want to achieve:

[image]

My question: Is there a cleaner way to implement this? I am concerned with the "cleanliness" of my code going forward with this hybrid TeamPlayerNode.